# TouchableOpacity with multiple child with onPress

Tags: react-native

I have FlatList with custom row item wrappen inside a TouchableOpacity. I would like to have multiple onPress inside the TouchableOpacity so that each child view can handle their respected job. Problem is that while on pressing the child view it does it's job but also parent `onPress` also gets executed. How to stop that?

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.doSomething()}>
  <Text>Some content</Text>
  <Icon name="trash" size={20} onPress={this.onDeleteItem(item)}/>
<TouchableOpacity>
```

In another word how to execute only `onDeleteItem` when user press on trash icon?

Any suggestion appreciated, thanks.

Comment: don't wrap them together with `Touchables`, wrap them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Containers from native-base in order to use zIndex properly. I also suffered allot because of zIndex. Then with containers it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add inside child function

`e.preventDefault()`

in suc an example

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.doSomething()}>
  <Text>Some content</Text>
  <Icon name="trash" size={20} onPress={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.onDeleteItem(item)
  }}/>
<TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your first onPress to the Text, or where-ever is more appropriate than the outer most container.

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <Text onPress={ () => this.doSomething()} >Some content</Text>
  <Icon name="trash" size={20} onPress={this.onDeleteItem(item)}/>
<TouchableOpacity>
```

Theres no way to avoid an event listener on the parent TouchableOpacity because it's wrapping all content. You would need to add some Containers/Contents (NativeBase) to modularize it more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I thought there would be a way to let parent know that child has consumed the event like you can do natively in android and iOS. Is that pattern exist in react-native at all?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you're referencing so I can't help. The only other suggestion would be have a toggleVariable in your state and then use a turnery for the first onPress...onPress={ this.state.doFunctionToggle ? this.doSomething() : undefined }

Comment: this is not a good practice in this case maybe your answer can help but for the other cases its not help